# Wiring for long runs

Tags: circuit-breaker

[image: Wiring plan]

Problem:
I didn't do my research before running a 200ft 12/2UF-B W/G  cable from my breaker to my shed branching off to my pergola in between. I saw that 12ga was for 20amps and then run with it without thinking about distance and voltage drop.  Well, i haven't powered it up yet but after coming across a calculator online it seems that i may have a problem on my hands.

My solution:
My solution will be to re-run from J-Box which is in-between shed and breaker panel using 6/2 wire and then from there branch off to the receptacles in pergola and shed with already buried 12/2 wires. My only concern is still the distance.  Will i be okay with this self-proposed solution?  From B to C there is barely any digging.  I just have to pop one of the deck boards up, drill holes through the studs to the end of the pergola, come out of the pergola, dig 18" for roughly 3ft,bore an inch hole into the concrete above and then go through the attic space and drop off the wall to the breaker panel.  From B to A however, i will have to trench another 75feet to get into the shed.

Comment: What are you trying to power at your shed and your pergola?  The 12AWG might be OK if the *actual loads* are light....

Comment: Dont buy the #6 yet, let's look at what you expect your *actual* loads will be...  Voltage drop calcs should be be done on real world loads, not breaker rating.

Comment: The shed will power up an LED bulb that uses only 10 watts.  It will also have two receptacles to charge my drill batteries and occasionally power up my mitre saw.

Comment: The pergola has a string of led lights that use about 20 watts.  I occasionally connect my projector and watch movies and games outside.

Answer (score 1):

As ThreePhaseEel has suggested and since its already installed maybe you should think about what your really need (demand verses connected). One thing you could do is install an extra conductor to your run to the jbox and get one circuit to the pagoda and one circuit to the shed. Also I would rethink my conductor size to the j-box. Having a #6 run 110 ft to a #12 running a further 90 ft wouldn't be my idea of a good circuit. To be sure you would have to do a drop calculation to the j-box and then another to the shed. In other words I don't see the benefit of running the #6. Also FYI a #6 does not fit in a standard 20 or 15 amp breaker. The largest they  accept is a #8. So you would have to splice another tail on to it in the panel.

I have also done what everyone has suggested. Only I have installed a buck/boost transformer. You could install it either at the load or line side of the circuit, and simple boost the voltage to whichever % your going to need to cover the drop. Remember you would have to do a voltage drop calculation with the necessary amperage at each location to get the proper boost. Also remember that  even though you adjust the voltage you will experience a power loss due to the resistance of the wire.

Example: If you installed a boost xfmr to cover a 10% loss. Then you would loose 10% of your power.  120V*20A=2400VA(W), less 10% would be (120V*20A)*90%=2160VA(W) or 2160W/120V=18A. See how it works.

Good luck on whatever you decide.

Comment: I understand your calculation and it makes sense.  I may just not have to use my mitre saw at the shed.  Will that make a difference?

Comment: @ROCKHEAD - Probably, motors have a hard time starting if there is too much resistance in a long circuit and is really not good for the machine. You can check to see if it starts to pull down or operates at a reduced speed. Remember electrical machinery actually like voltages to be a little high rather that an under voltage.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this idea is feasible but I will mention it here and the electricians that monitor this site can comment or give a thumbs up or thumbs down. " Power this line with 240 volts and add a step-down transformer (240 to 120 volts) at each destination. Each transformer would be sized for the expected load at each destination.

Comment: Are line-level transformers something you see in residential wiring? I don't think I ever have.

Comment: I have 2 sets a 5kva and 10kva jumping up to 600v then back down after very long runs at my farm, I have used this method on other country properties with runs in the 300-500' but would not say it's common. This method can be much cheaper picking up a couple transformers on line than the massive size of wire that it would take to run this length and maintain the voltage.

Comment: I am a newbie and will have to research this.  Also, are these weather and waterproof?